# Does NativeScript support npm link or symlink modules? If not, then what are the alternatives?

Tags: nativescript

I have a commons package that I share across my projects. But when I tried linking it to my nativescript project, the app says it cannot find the module.

So what are my alternatives? In react native, although it too doesn't support symlink, it does support relative paths using the right metro configuration. But I also tried relative paths in my NS project but it still fails to find my commons module.

Thanks.

Comment: Which flavour you are using for development?

Comment: @Manoj I’m using angular.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried symlink, but [xplat](https://nstudio.io/xplat/) could be a better option since you are using Angular.

If you are really interested in symlink, then there is a [plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/symlink-resolver) you might want to checkout.